# simplifying and sorting the creation of a new array out of an existing one

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[
   {country: 'a', region: 1}
   {country: 'a', region: 2}
   {country: 'a', region: 3}
   {country: 'b', region: 4}
   {country: 'b', region: 5}
   {country: 'c', region: 6}
   {country: 'd', region: 7}
   {country: 'e', region: 8}
]
```

I want to end up with an array like this:

```
[
   {country: 'a', region: [1, 2, 3]}
   {country: 'b', region: [4, 5]}
   {country: 'c', region: [6]}
   {country: 'd', region: [7]}
   {country: 'e', region: [8]}
]
```

I've been trying the following but I'm stuck at the part where I want to push the result in the existing byCountry array...

Also I feel like filter might not be the best function for this and it can probably be a lot less complex than how I wrote it.

```
 let byCountry = []

    regions.forEach( (region) => {
      const filter = byCountry.filter( country => country.country === region.country )

      if (filter.length > 0) {
        const filteredCountry = filter[0]['country']
        const result = _.find(byCountry, country => {
          return country.country === filteredCountry
        })
// stuck here

      } else {
        const newCountry = {
          country: region.country,
          regions: [region.region],
        }

        byCountry.push(newCountry)
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just convert your array to a hashmap which maps countries to multiple regions `{<country>: Array<regions>}` and convert it back to an array afterwards:

```js
const records = [
      {country: 'a', region: 1},
      {country: 'a', region: 2},
      {country: 'a', region: 3},
      {country: 'b', region: 4},
      {country: 'b', region: 5},
      {country: 'c', region: 6},
      {country: 'd', region: 7},
      {country: 'e', region: 8}
    ];

const regionsByCountry = new Map();

records.forEach(record => {
  if (!regionsByCountry.has(record.country)) {
    regionsByCountry.set(record.country, []);
  }

  regionsByCountry.get(record.country).push(record.region);
});

const merged = Array.from(regionsByCountry)
                    .map(([country, region]) => ({country,region}));
                    
console.log(merged)
```

You can either use a modern `Map` which has a readable API, or a plain object literal `{}`.

Docs for Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, it was the easiest for me to digest so I picked yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like this:

The aim is to create an object with each `country` value as key and `{country: 'a', region: []}` as value. Then simply use `Object.values` to get the output.

```js
const regions=[{country:'a',region:1},{country:'a',region:2},{country:'a',region:3},{country:'b',region:4},{country:'b',region:5},{country:'c',region:6},{country:'d',region:7},{country:'e',region:8}]

const merged = regions.reduce((acc, {country,region}) => 
  ((acc[country] = acc[country] || {country, region: []}).region.push(region), acc)
, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Here's a simplified version of the above code:

```js
const regions = [{country:'a',region:1},{country:'a',region:2},{country:'a',region:3},{country:'b',region:4},{country:'b',region:5},{country:'c',region:6},{country:'d',region:7},{country:'e',region:8}]

const merged = regions.reduce((acc, {country,region}) => {
  acc[country] = acc[country] || {country, region: []};
  acc[country].region.push(region);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Comment: this is probably the best answer. It's more concise I suppose. But I find it hard to understand and to read as well

Answer (score 0):

Collect the values to a Map using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), then convert back to an object using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const data = [{"country":"a","region":1},{"country":"a","region":2},{"country":"a","region":3},{"country":"b","region":4},{"country":"b","region":5},{"country":"c","region":6},{"country":"d","region":7},{"country":"e","region":8}]
  
const result = Array.from(
  data.reduce((m, { country, region }) => 
    m.set(country, [...(m.get(country) || []), region])
  , new Map),
  ([country, region]) => ({ country, region })
)

console.log(result)
```